# Heroku error with rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed a 1 page, completely static rails app to heroku. There's no database and no actual code beyond the routes and some html. After pushing to heroku, trying to load the page and checking logs, this is the error I'm getting.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
```

Are there any rails 3.1.0 compatibility issues with heroku? I'm kind of lost on this one.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use any database just remove activerecord. To do it change `require 'rails/all'` in `config/application.rb` to:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Comment: I don't need to use a database right this second but I'm sure I will at some point. Is there a way of fixing it without removing activerecord?

Comment: You can add activerecord later when you need. (`require "active_record/railtie"`)

Comment: So are you saying that rails 3.1.0 breaks on heroku _unless_ you're using a database?